# Gather results from rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am new to rundeck and I wrote a basic script that will check if a file exists on a bunch of nodes ie it returns true or false. What I want to do next is then to parse whether the file exists or not and then send a single email with the results saying something like node x doesn't have the file, node y does have the file etc. My question is how can I aggregate the results from the other nodes so that I can loop through it and email it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple echo in your script to mention the existence of the file and then turn on Send Notification for the job, so that you can receive an email with the Log. This log will have the output of your script.